# Closest prime problem: What is this part of code doing? next(x for x in count(0) if isPrime(s+x) )

Tags: python, primes, python-itertools

I was checking the solutions for a codewars kata, related to getting the closest prime number. Here is the link of the kata for more information.
[Transform to Prime](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a946d9fba1bb5135100007c/python)

But I didn't understand the solution of a user, who made this:

```
from itertools import count

def isPrime(n):
    return n == 2 or n%2 and all(n%x for x in range(3,int(n**.5)+1,2))

def minimum_number(numbers):
    s = sum(numbers)
    return next(x for x in count(0) if isPrime(s+x))
```

What is doing the function `next(x for x in count(0) if isPrime(s+x))` ? Because the `count(0)` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `count(0)` goes from 0 to infinity. I guess the user doesn't know where the script stops, so he couldn't use `range()`

Comment: i think ``count(0)`` is the simplest part to understand here. ``count(0)`` gives you 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [`count(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) just returns an infinite iterator that starts at `0` and never stops (ie: `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, on and on forever).

The user then uses `x for x in count(0) if isPrime(s+x)` to create a generator around this infinite iterator, using a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/). The syntax of generator expressions are pretty straight-forward: for every output `x` from `count(0)` that makes `isPrime(s+x)` true, output `x`. Basically, the original `count()` iterator is filtered to only the outputs which satisfy the condition `isPrime(s+x)`.

Finally, the user uses the `next()` function on that generator, which gets the next output of that generator. Because the generator is being freshly created from that generator expression, this is just the first number that the generator produces. Or, the first non-negative integer value of `x` which makes `isPrime(s+x)` return `True`.

Answer (score 3):

`count(0)` is an infinite sequence generator and an overkill for the problem at hand.  Based on [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) (which has been proven), there will always be a prime between `s` and `2*s`, so the function could use a simple range:

```
def minimum_number(numbers):
    s = sum(numbers)
    return next(x for x in range(s) if isPrime(s+x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
return next(x for x in count(0) if condition)
```

`count(0)` is an iterable that gives an infinite series of `int`s (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5…)

`next()` gives the next value in an iterable. Calling it once will give the first value.

So the above statement will return the first number in that series that meets the condition. Here's another way to write it:

```py
x = 0
while not condition:
    x += 1
return x
```